# Не запускается spring boot приложение

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Всем привет! Есть сущность, есть репозиторий. При запуске спринг отказывается запускаться и выдает следующее:

```
2021-03-15 14:08:50.721 ERROR 3468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: 
Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'mailConfirmationRepo' defined in com.company.repos.MailConfirmationRepo defined in 
@EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot 
resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: 
com.company.domain.MailConfirmation
```

Сущность:

```java
package com.company.domain;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "mail_confirmations")
@Data
public class MailConfirmation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String code = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 6);

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String mail;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean confirmed = false;

    public MailConfirmation() {
    }

    public MailConfirmation(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}
```

Репозиторий:

```java
package com.company.domain;

import com.company.domain.MailConfirmation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface MailConfirmationRepo extends JpaRepository<MailConfirmation, Long> {

    MailConfirmation getByCode(String code);

}
```

Файл миграции:

```sql
create table mail_confirmations
(
    id                int8 not null unique,
    code              varchar(6) not null unique,
    mail              varchar(255) not null,
    confirmed         boolean not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8085

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:postgres}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:}
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.freemarker.expose-request-attributes=true

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю Вы немного ошиблись с аннотацией, вместо аннотации `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` используйте `javax.persistence.Id`.

Я так предполагаю, потому что увидел такой ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644765/8696557.
Там говорится что для реляционных баз данных используется именно вторая аннотация, PostgreSQL как раз реляционная база данных.

И в целом советую искать причину проблемы в названиях Exception и их сообщениях, в Вашем случае это было:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: 
com.company.domain.MailConfirmation
```

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо!